# "Access is denied" message while deploying spring app in tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, access-denied, filenotfoundexception

While trying to deploy my spring app on tomcat 6 I get an error saying

```
java.util.logging.errormanager:4
java.io.filenotfoundexception: c:\program files\apache software foundation\tomcat 6.0\logs\catalina.2010.02.16.log <Access is denied>
  at java.io.fileoutputstream.openappend <native method>
  at java.io.fileoutputstream.<init><unknown source>
  at java.io.filewriter.<init><unknown source>
  at apache.juli.filehandler.open<filehandler.java:259>
  at apache.juli.filehandler.open<filehandler.java:59>
  at apache.juli.filehandler.open<filehandler.java:50>
  at sun.reflect.nativeconstructoraccessorImpl.newInstance0<native method>
  at sun.reflect.delegatingconstructoraccessorImpl.newInstance<unknown source>
  at sun.reflect.constructor.newInstance<unknown source>
  at java.lang.class.newinstance0<unknown source>
  at org.apache.juli.classloaderlogmanager.readconfiguration<classloaderlogmanager.java:418>
  .....
  .....
  at java.util.logging.logmanager$2.run<unknown source>
  .....
  .....
```

Is this because Tomcat hasn't been installed properly? Or do I need some permissions to use Tomcat? Or are some important tomcat files missing? Or something else?

Comment: You need to grant rw permission to catalina.2010.02.16.log, for the tomcat group

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Is there really a tomcat group in Windows?

Comment: @Peter Lang: Is this for Windows?  I've been working Tomcat on RH lately...

Comment: This is for windows XP professional 2002

Comment: check the permissions on the catalina.log file, or other catalina.[date].log files.  Make the permissions match on the log file you get the error for.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I was guessing because of the `c:\program files\` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the following file exists:

```
c:\program files\apache software foundation\tomcat 6.0\logs\catalina.2010.02.16.log
```

Your exception says `<Access is denied>`, so maybe the file is open in another application or you are missing permissions?

Comment: ... and if the file in question does not exist, check that your application / its account has the permissions required to create the file in that directory.

Comment: File doesnt exist. How do I check for permissions? Unable to create/cut/copy a new folder in Tomcat directory. Says"access is denied." Also, While trying to export the project as a .war file from eclipse into the tomcat webapps folder, it says an error has occured.

Comment: You can try to change permissions. On Windows XP for example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419/EN-US/

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by running netBeans (or whichever IDE you are using to run the application) as an administrator. That gives you access permissions.

Answer (score 3):

right click on log folder and in security give yourself proper WRITE permission and make sure folders are not in read only mode.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're working on a machine that has some security policies in place that restrict you from installing software yourself. This is very common in most organizations nowadays.

Do the following:

1. Uninstall tomcat.
2. Find a folder where you can read/write into (eg. D:\neetu)
3. Install tomcat in the above folder.

Run tomcat.
It should work now.

Comment: Hi, what were you referring to when you said "these new users (1 rep point users) dont bother to use the site as they should"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the necessary system rights to deploy Tomcat. But now its throwing an error saying the war file cannot be unzipped.Also, How can I find out which port Tomcat is currently using?

Comment: Looks like you marked the question as 'answered'. Maybe you would need to open up another question on the site?

Answer (score 1):

After installing Apache Tomcat you must give the OS user who will be running the Tomcat server write/update rights to the directories: temp, logs, work.

Comment: How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has no access rights to the c:\program files\ folders. There are ways to get around this, but the easiest way will be to install Tomcat in another directory, e.g in your user area (C:\Users).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I right click on eclipse and gave it administrative rights

Comment: how is this different from the answer by @Sai over a year ago?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is that you need to run Tomcat with **Administrator Permission**. And this access denied will never occur.